# Unit testing ASP MVC 5 attribute routes

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

how can I unit test ASP MVC 5 attribute routes?
There are plenty of solutions for MVC 4, but nothing for unit testing attribute routing on MVC 5 as far as I can see.

I found a library called MvcRouteTester for MVC5, but there's no clear-cut way to actually set up a route collection from the attributes.

Comment: I have also searched... Did you manage to set up a fixture to check MVC5 routes.

Comment: No. In the end I decided that this was implementation detail and thus should not be unit tested (at least not in C#) and relied on end-to-end tests

Comment: That's what we're arguing too. I hate that I sometimes change attributes and the routes for get and post are sometimes not congruent. Thanks for the response.